# User faced scheduler for rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, schedule

I need to implement user faced scheduler, like users have reports and might choose schedule when they want those reports being sent to them.
Requirements are quote complex, like there should be schedules like each 12 hours, each 30 minutes, each second day, at Fridays at 1am, last Sunday of the months etc.

Is there Rails solution for that our should I create it from the ground?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Most schedulers for rails and ruby depend on a static file. You can use a queuing system like Delayed Job and make every job enqueue itself for next time after success. Or you can do a basic SheduledJob model which relates to the user, and stores the periodicity, next execution and last execution. And use a normal (frequent) scheduled task engine like clockwork to check for pending jobs.